# Cannot ping, or map to qnap, but can use existing maps normally

Tags: windows, networking, qnap

ICMP attempts (ping, tracert) fail as unreachable, nslookup returns expected results.  I CAN still existing mapped drives from the same host.

I'm not really even sure where to begin with something like that. Thoughts?

Comment: I suggest you get a copy of Wireshark (packet sniffer) and install it. Run it and see if you can determine where the packets are failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to isolate the problem using tcpdump / wireshark on src & dst of the host interface. you should be able to figure out where the traffic is getting stopped.
Check firewalls to see if some ACL is blocking traffic. Also, make sure File & Printer Sharing (echo request) is enabled on the firewall on host machines.